# Lenovo IdeaPad 100 - Issue with Bluetooth (Bus 002 Device 002: ID 258a:1005 )

Tags: drivers, bluetooth

I'm trying to find out why bluetooth search doesn't work. I've followed this tutorial steps [here](https://outhereinthefield.wordpress.com/2014/03/01/ubuntu-13-10-and-bluetooth-on-broadcom-bcm43142-wifibt-combo-adapter/) but `dmesg` did not give me a message such as "can't load firmware, may not work correctly"

*Note: wifi works great, though searching for  258a:1005 in google showed me wifi problems insetead of bluetooth.*

Have you got any ideas how to fix bluetooth?

`lsb_release -a`

```
LSB Version:    core-2.0-amd64:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-amd64:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-amd64:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:security-4.0-amd64:security-4.0-noarch:security-4.1-amd64:security-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

`hciconfig`

```
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
BD Address: 4C:BB:58:AA:A6:11  ACL MTU: 820:8  SCO MTU: 255:16
UP RUNNING PSCAN 
RX bytes:1293 acl:0 sco:0 events:87 errors:0
TX bytes:1196 acl:0 sco:0 commands:84 errors:0
```

`lsusb`

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f2:b49f Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 174f:1169 Syntek 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 258a:1005  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`dmesg`

```
[   21.015877] usb 2-4: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
[   21.017463] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: Realtek 
[   21.019029] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001
[   28.055881] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.19
[   28.058540] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   28.058546] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   28.058560] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   28.058564] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   28.058582] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized

[   30.836430] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   30.836445] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   30.836454] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   31.227794] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   31.227799] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   31.227809] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   32.852383] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link down
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include `usb-devices | grep -iB2 bluetooth` as I don't think the 258a:1005 is bluetooth, more likely to be a USB mouse